# Best Practice: Ansys FEA Output Data Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-s3, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage

I'm trying to make this as least subjective as possible by providing finite inputs and parameters. I truly want to know what is the most resource affective, given the constraints. Given my available options listed below, what is the best use of resources to store ANSYS FEA Output Data. Recent jobs need quick access, historic can be slower but retrievable within a reasonable amount of time (30min - 45min).

1. Existing 16TB NAS, copy job to Amazon S3 bucket
2. New NAS (48-64 TB), retire existing NAS
3. Expand VMware SAN, new share, use VEEAM to manage backup to existing AWS S3 Bucket
4. Expand user's workstation from 2x 12TB HDDs to 4x 18TB HDDs RAID 10.

Points:

- we are a lean enterprise and need to keep output data as opposed to smaller FEA input data due to resource and time constraints or rerunning jobs.
- Could swing for either $10kUSD, 5 year investment or as much as $1kUSD per month if services like S3 buckets are required.

Comment: Your question is fairly vague, it assumes some kind of industry specific knowledge. Suggest you edit your question to specify more along the lines of data volumes, maximum, access times, etc. Also interested in penalties if you fail to keep data - if you could get find $50K for losing data then putting the data tiered in S3 may make more sense than local storage.

Comment: After thinking about the root of my question, I now believe this just comes down to a local vs cloud data storage problem. The specific answers to my question would just be redundant considering the local v. cloud examples which I'm sure are just a google search away. Sorry, I'm new to the SE / SO world, I think this question should be marked for deletion?